# Casting C++ class into another one to create OpenCV trackbar handle

Tags: c++, class, opencv, type-conversion

To not mess around with global variables and functions, I'd like to use a function of a class as a function for a trackbar handle in OpenCV. Following code illustrates the idea:

```
void cam::set_Trackbarhandler(int i, void *func)
{
    /* This function might be called whenever a trackbar position is changed */
}

void cam::create_Trackbars(void)
{
    /**
     * create trackbars and insert them into main window.
     * 3 parameters are:
     * the address of the variable that is changing when the trackbar is moved,
     * the maximum value the trackbar can move,
     * and the function that is called whenever the trackbar is moved
     */

    const string trck_name = "Exposure";
    char wnd_name[128];
    get_Mainwindowname(wnd_name, sizeof(wnd_name));


    createTrackbar(trck_name, //Name of the trackbar
                    wnd_name, //Name of the parent window
                    &setting, //value that's changed
                    (int)out_max, //maximum value
                    this->set_Trackbarhandler); //pointer to the function that's called
}
```

I hope that outlines it. The error I get when compiling reads

```
error: cannot convert 'cam::set_Trackbarhandler' from type 'void (cam::)(int, void*)' to type 'cv::TrackbarCallback {aka void (*)(int, void*)}'|
```

Is there a way to cast `void (cam::)(int, void*)` into a simple `void (*)(int, void*)` or do I have to use a global function, that is

```
void set_Trackbarhandler(int i, void *func)
```

? If I have to do it like that, my last resort is to use the void pointer (see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) and send a pointer to the class back in, as

```
    createTrackbar(trck_name,
                    wnd_name,
                    &setting,
                    (int)out_max,
                    set_Trackbarhandler, //now a global function
                    this);
```

I guess. In the `set_Trackbarhandler` function I'd make a cast like

```
cam *ptr = static_cast<cam *>(func);
```

Sounds a bit complicated, though.

Comment: You can't convert a pointer to member to a pointer to function. If you don't want to use a global function, declare it in a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well. you need *some* indirection, but it's not that bad...

```
class cam
{
public:

    void myhandler(int value)
    {
       // real work here, can use 'this'
    }

    static void onTrack(int value, void* ptr)
    {
        cam* c = (cam*)(ptr);
        c->myhandler(value);
    }
};

createTrackbar(trck_name,
                    wnd_name,
                    &setting,
                    (int)out_max,
                    cam::onTrack, //now a static member
                    this);
```

Comment: This works great. Want to stress the importance of the sixth argument to createTrackbar(), which is how the static callback gets a handle to the instance. I had not been passing this in, and it took me five minutes with gdb wondering why this wasn't working. But alas: it does, exactly as typed.